# Can we use SpanNearQuery in phonetic index?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

I've implemented a lucene-based software to index more than 10 millions of person's names and these names can be written on different ways like "Luíz" and "Luis". The index was created using the phonetic values of the respective tokens (a custom analyzer was created).

Currently, I'm using QueryParser to query for a given name with good results. But, in the book "Lucene in Action" is mentioned that SpanNearQuery can improve my queries using the proximity of tokens. I've played with the SpanNearQuery against a non-phonetic index of name and the results were superior compared to QueryParser.

As we should query using the same analyzer used to indexing, I couldn't find how I can use my custom phonetic analyzer and SpanNearQuery at same time, or rephrasing:

```
    how can I use SpanNearQuery on the phonetic index?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is:  Wouldn't a phrase query with slop do the job?  That would certainly be the easiest way:

```java
"term1 term2"~5
```

This will use your phonetic analyzer, and produce a proximity query with the resulting tokens.

---

So, if you *really do* need to use SpanQueries here (perhaps you are using fuzzy queries or wildcards or some such, or PhraseQuery has been leering menacingly at you and you want nothing more to do with it), you'll need to do the analysis yourself.  You can do this by getting a TokenStream from `Analyzer.tokenStream`, and iterating through the analyzed tokens.

If you are using a phonetic algorithm that produces a single code per term (soundex, for example):

```java
SpanNearQuery.Builder nearBuilder = new SpanNearQuery.Builder("text", true);
nearBuilder.setSlop(4);

TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("text", queryStringToParse);
stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
stream.reset();
while(stream.incrementToken()) {
    CharTermAttribute token = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    nearBuilder.addClause(new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", token.toString())));
}
Query finalQuery = nearBuilder.build();
stream.close();
```

If you are using a double metaphone, where you can have 1-2 terms at the same position, it's a bit more complex, as you'll need to consider those position increments:

```java
SpanNearQuery.Builder nearBuilder = new SpanNearQuery.Builder("text", true);
nearBuilder.setSlop(4);

TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("text", "through and through");
stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
stream.addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
stream.reset();
String queuedToken = null;
while(stream.incrementToken()) {
    CharTermAttribute token = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    PositionIncrementAttribute increment = stream.getAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);

    if (increment.getPositionIncrement() == 0) {
        nearBuilder.addClause(new SpanOrQuery(
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", queuedToken)),
                new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", token.toString()))
                ));
        queuedToken = null;
    }
    else if (increment.getPositionIncrement() >= 1 && queuedToken != null) {
        nearBuilder.addClause(new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", queuedToken)));
        queuedToken = token.toString();
    }
    else {
        queuedToken = token.toString();
    }
}

if (queuedToken != null) {
    nearBuilder.addClause(new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", queuedToken)));
}

Query finalQuery = nearBuilder.build();
stream.close();
```